# What properties get changed when you click on a control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, mouseevent, eventtrigger

I am trying to find a workaround to applying a setter in an `EventTrigger`, I want to set a property on the Click event, does any one know what property gets changed when you click a Control so I can test this in a `Trigger`?

Comment: This depends on which control you are talking about. A CheckBox will change its Checked property state on Click other controls have other behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit vague. Maybe the IsFocused property, for a UIElement which is Focusable, is the kind of thing you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`MouseLeftButtonDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.